# Cause: lateinit property _buildFeatureValues has not been initialized

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, build.gradle, jetbrains-ide

When I Upgrade Gradle from 4.2.2 to 7.3.0 I got Below Error

**Cause: lateinit property _buildFeatureValues has not been initialized**

So How to solve this error?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What result do you get when building from command line by Gradle?

Comment: I just started seeing this error as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same error as you facing but as Andrey suggested I did build using command line and full error which I didn't get when I directly build don't know why?

But It's through error related `flat dir` and `aar` file so I did removed **flat dir** code and change **aar file implementation code** now It's started to build and my app started to install.

If you are use dagger hilt you should change your dependency as below to avoid **Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY error in runtime.
```

---

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.42"     
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.43.2"     
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.42"     
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43.2"     
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'     
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"     
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'     
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.1"
```